# Can I not loop over an array after a foreach in php?

Tags: php

I've started teaching myself php and have found something I don't understand. If it is really simple, my apologies! I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong, or if it is a quirk of foreach loops it would be useful to know what and why. I was trying this out purely as an example to see how the loops work in php, so I just added them one after another in a file.

My code (based off an example in a book):

```
<?php

$p = array(
    'Copier' => "Numero Uno",
    'Inkjet' => "Numero Dos",
    'Laser' => "Numero Tres",
    'Photo' => "Numero Cuatro"
);

foreach ($p as $item => $desc) {
    echo "$item: $desc<br />";
}

echo "<br />";
echo "---";
echo "<br /><br />";

while (list($item2, $desc2) = each($p)) {
    echo "$item2: $desc2<br />";
}
```

With this code I get this output:

```
Copier: Numero Uno
Inkjet: Numero Dos
Laser: Numero Tres
Photo: Numero Cuatro

---
```

If I swap the foreach and while loops I get this (which is what I expect):

```
Copier: Numero Uno
Inkjet: Numero Dos
Laser: Numero Tres
Photo: Numero Cuatro

---

Copier: Numero Uno
Inkjet: Numero Dos
Laser: Numero Tres
Photo: Numero Cuatro
```

Because I've not been getting an output for the `while` if it runs after the `foreach`, I renamed item and desc just in case (hence why `$item2`, `$desc2`).

While writing this it occurred to me to make a new variable array from `$p` and try with that (`$p2`).

```
$p2 = $p;

while (list($item2, $desc2) = each($p2)) {
    echo "$item2: $desc2<br />";
}
```

This works. I also tried repeating the foreach loop again exactly the same (copy and pasted to where the while was) and that works.

Does the `foreach` somehow arrange the `$p` array in a way that the `while` doesn't understand? What is going on here? Is there a useful way to see what is going on under the hood in php?

Comment: @JayBlanchard oooh really? I haven't come across that yet. Is that just for foreach? I read on another post that foreach automatically sets the pointer to the first element in the array when it is being used (is this true?) which would explain why it works when duplicated. So while doesn't do this and doesn't need to be reset?

Comment: ah... comment disappeared.

Comment: `each` is deprecated as of PHP 7.2. If it's like other deprecated stuff in PHP, it won't actually be removed for a while, but just FYI.

Comment: Ah okay. Yeh the book I'm using is from 2009 so I expected some differences. There might be more than I expected...

Comment: Yeah, quite a bit has changed since then. btw, `$p2` worked because the pointer position isn't copied along with the array contents. It's reset to the start on the new array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry, I forgot ;)

Comment: No worries @dgBP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing on PHP7 I could not replicate your problem, but if you're running on an earlier version of PHP you need to [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) the array pointer back to the beginning of the array:

```
$p = array(
    'Copier' => "Numero Uno",
    'Inkjet' => "Numero Dos",
    'Laser' => "Numero Tres",
    'Photo' => "Numero Cuatro"
);

foreach ($p as $item => $desc) {
    echo "$item: $desc<br />";
}

reset($p);

echo "<br />";
echo "---";
echo "<br /><br />";

while (list($item, $desc) = each($p)) {
    echo "$item: $desc<br />";
}
```

This produces ([example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/098891e9eb46838677e824589dc33bc94c809306)):

> Copier: Numero Uno
> Inkjet: Numero Dos
> Laser: Numero Tres
> Photo: Numero Cuatro
> ---
> Copier: Numero Uno
> Inkjet: Numero Dos
> Laser: Numero Tres
> Photo: Numero Cuatro

Comment: Works perfectly with reset! This is actually really useful to know just in case something else falls over when it doesn't access the pointer in the correct place.

Comment: on a side note, there's pretty much never any reason to use `each()` ... ever.

Comment: @WheatBeak can I ask why? It seems to me here that while each is a safer option to use than foreach for exactly the reason above.

Comment: I think the difference is because foreach doesn't move the internal array pointer any more in PHP 7. I think I remember reading that somewhere.

Comment: It's very old, slower than `foreach`, more to write, just really isn't useful in practice.

Comment: That was my reminder to check on something other than 7 @Don'tPanic

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for all your help. This is very useful to know :)